# Как добиться смещения контента за пределы страницы

Tags: html, css

Есть меню адаптивное для телефона, при открытии весь контент не смещается в право, а сжимается, как сделать чтобы все содержимое сместилось не сжимаясь.

```css
.sidemenu-container, .navbar-collapse {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    float: left;
```

Comment: Мало кода. Не понятно что и где происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Меню прячем так, контент смещаем так

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(".item").toggleClass("visible");
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("na");
  $("html,body").toggleClass("noscroll");
})
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .3s;
}

html,
body {
  perspective: 600px;
}

.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  left: -400px;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.button i {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 4px auto;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

.visible {
  left: 0;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20vw;
  padding-left: 30px;
  z-index: 21;
}

.wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(#fbfbfb, #dfdfdf);
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.na {
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transform: rotateY(10deg)translateX(300px)scale(.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="item" tabindex="-1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<span class="button">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
  </span>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sect1">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>
      Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных, и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```